# Show scroll bar top and bottom of the grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to use scroll bar in both side of grid or scrolling grid on mouse move.

I have tried below code but bottom scrollbar works but top scrollbar does not.

```html
<script >     
                    $(function () {
                       
                    $(".wrapper1").scroll(function () {
                        $(".wrapper2")
                            .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
                    });
                  
                    $(".wrapper2").scroll(function () {
                        $(".wrapper1")
                            .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
                    });
                    });

                    $(window).load(function () {
                        $('.div1').css('width', $('.div2').outerWidth());
                    });
               
       
    </script>
```

enter code here

This is css of div

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper1, .wrapper2 {
        width: 900px;
        border: none 0px RED;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .wrapper1 {
        height: 20px;
    }

    /*.wrapper2 {
        height: 200px;
    }*/

    .div1 {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .div2 {
        width: 1000px;
        background-color: #88FF88;
        overflow: auto;
    }

  </style>
```

This is html

```html
    <div class="wrapper1">
     <div class="div1">
      &nbsp;
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="wrapper2">
     <div id="div2">
          <%-- my grid-- %>                                   
       </div>
       </div>
```

And this is my result

[image]

But top sidebar does not work

When I paste same jQuery function in browser console and enter then both slider work properly

Comment: Why are you using JQuery? You can use CSS for this. And do you want that the scroll bar is moving with the other scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

Small observation: the css for div2 should be by id selector(#).

```
#div2 {
        width: 1000px;
        background-color: #88FF88;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```